# Template substitution failure with empty parameter pack using a Y-combinator

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to make a function that will read from a pipe to a buffer using `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor`. I use `async_read_some` rather than `boost::asio::async_read` because it is important for me to be immediately notified as soon as a chunk of data is read. What I want to do after reading data from the pipe is

1. Move the writer pointer of my buffer
2. Do something with the newly got data
3. Schedule the read of more data

I wanted to duplicate as little code as possible, so I ended up with a functional programming mess that I would be very curious to know why it does not work.

```cpp
asio::posix::stream_descriptor inputPipe{context, input.fd};
char buffer[2048]; // simple buffer for demonstration purposes
char* end = buffer + 2048;
char* writer = buffer;

// the interesting part
yCombinator([&](auto&& self_) {
    inputPipe.async_read_some(asio::buffer(writer, end - writer), [&](boost::system::error_code errorCode_, size_t transferedCount_) -> void {
        writer += transferedCount_;
        
        // ... be something, go somewhere, do something, make things change ...
        
        self_(self_); // self_ contains the async_read_some, so it schedules the next read
    });
})();
```

Where I proudly present `yCombinator` as:

```cpp
template<typename Fn>
constexpr auto yCombinator(Fn&& fn_) noexcept {
    return [capture = std::tuple{std::forward<Fn>(fn_)}](auto&&... args_) constexpr noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<Fn, decltype(args_)...>)->std::invoke_result_t<Fn, decltype(args_)...> {
        return std::invoke(std::get<0>(capture), std::get<0>(capture), std::forward<decltype(args_)>(args_)...);
    };
}
```

Currently the aforementioned code fails to compile. G++ complains that `candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with args_:auto = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result<(lambda at redacted.cpp:80:21)>'`. I understand this has to have something to do with the trailing return type of the lambda being returned from `yCombinator`. I suppose that the issue could be that `args_` is an empty parameter pack, but I am not really sure how to deal with that. But at the same time, if this is the issue, than why does everything seem okay with the `std::is_nothrow_invocable_v` trait?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], is the IO stuff at all relevant to the error?

Comment: @PasserBy I'd say it's quite needed as `async_read_some` is what the lambda is given to. I could choose a different function, but I don't think that matters. Its just a function that takes a function as a second parameter. It can do whatever it does - its irrelevant - but I think there is no need to replace it with some other function.

Comment: Emphasis on "minimal" in [mre]. If it's irrelevant, you remove them. Not only does it help readers, you very well might solve the problem in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

First, there is a mismatch between return type/noexcept and function body:
miss `Fn` in the formers

```
template<typename Fn>
constexpr auto yCombinator(Fn&& fn_) noexcept {
    return [capture = std::tuple{std::forward<Fn>(fn_)}](auto&&... args_) constexpr
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<Fn, Fn, decltype(args_)...>)
//                                               ^^
        -> std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Fn, decltype(args_)...>
//                                  ^^
    {
        return std::invoke(std::get<0>(capture),
                           std::get<0>(capture),
                           std::forward<decltype(args_)>(args_)...);
    };
}
```

Then, to deduce non-provided return type, we have to *"look"* in the body, and so use `self_` return type before we deduce it.

Solution is to provide type explicitly:

```
yCombinator([&](auto&& self_) -> void
//                            ^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
    self_(self_);
})();
```

Comment: Oh, I must have got entangled in all those specifiers. Thanks for pointing the lack of the second `Fn`. And the explicit trailing return type, too.